# First-order non-linear differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{1}{y} = f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

I was trying to solve the following question: $\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{1}{y} = f(x)$, with f(x) is a function we know. 
I tried seperable method and exact function but it did not work. Is there anyway to solve it?

Comment: This is an Abel ODE; multiply through by $y$ and then see [here](https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0125.pdf).